# How Can i Make a column to fill all the way to the sides in bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I may sound stupid, but this is all new to me.
I'm guessing I have overlooked something.I have no ideea how to fill the white spaces between my columns(end-to-end)

This is my code:

```
<div class="container" id="cfoot">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                  <h3>despre noi</h3>
                  <p>Pensiunea Delia</p>
                    <p>Echipa Noastra</p>
               </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                   <h3>link-uri utile</h3>
                    <p>Intrebari frecvente</p>
                    <p>Serviciile noastre</p>
                    <p>Contact</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <h3>ultimele postari</h3>
                     <p>Titlul postare blog vine aici</p>
                     <p>Titlul postare blog vine aici</p>
                     <p>Titlul postare blog vine aici</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <img src="imgs/logodelia.png" alt="logobottom">
                    <p>@ 2014 Pensiunea Delia. Designed by Kinkara Web</p>
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
#cfoot.container{
    background-color:#f4f4f4;
    color:#6c6c6c;
    background-image:none;
}
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Can you please add all of your CSS? I've added this JSFiddle for you as it will be easier for others to help: http://jsfiddle.net/XEF8v/

Comment: Thank you.Here is the linl  [link]http://jsfiddle.net/XEF8v/1/

Comment: I'm not seeing any CSS for the "col-lg" classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I use developer tools to look at the markup, I'm seeing this applied by the browser:

```
body {
   display: block;
   margin: 8px;
}
```

If you simply add

```
body {
   margin: 0;
}

.container {
    margin: 10px; // adjust as needed
}
```

I think you'll be on your way.

---

note: you're also missing the Bootstrap row

```
<div class="row">
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XEF8v/1/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite clear on your question. I think you are asking us how you can use bootstrap to achieve the layout of four columns, like in the second image that you have posted.

You can get most of the way there by using Bootstraps built-in grid system.

Overview of Bootstrap's grid system: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1" id="col-1"><!-- empty space on left --></div>
        <div class="col-md-2" id="col-2"><!-- despre noi column --></div>
        <div class="col-md-2" id="col-3"><!-- link-uri-title column --></div>
        <div class="col-md-2" id="col-4"><!-- ultimele column --></div>
        <div class="col-md-4" id="col-5"><!-- delea logo column --></div>
        <div class="col-md-1" id="col-6"><!-- empty space on right --></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The col-md-<#> class determines the horizontal width of a column. Per Bootstrap's documentation, these numbers should add up to 12.

Comment: I know the grid system , In the first picture I already have 4 columns.The problem is i want to somehow fill the white color that surrounds the container.Currently in the container i have the #f4f4f4 color , but I want it to surround the container as well.Don't know how to explain.I have updated the pictures.

Comment: I think you removed the images by mistake. I can no longer see them.

Comment: I think you essentially want to create empty space around all four sides of your page content. In which case [Brad's Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24791178/1669860) should do the job. If you want to create as little custom CSS as possible you should be able to just add a row before and after the row containing all of your content, and then use the extra "empty space" rows like I provided in my example above.